# How to get rid of small gaps between horizontally aligned images?

Tags: css, html, image

Please see http://www.rcblue.com/test/Toby.html . There are very narrow vertical gaps between the images. How to get rid of them in `html5`, without using `<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">`?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to get rid of the cell padding and cell spacing of the table containing the images.

Basically, your `table` tag will look like:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">...</table>
```

---

I do recommend against using a `table` as an image gallery. I would instead just place them all in a `div` and apply CSS heights, widths, paddings, and margins to your liking.

For example:

HTML: (closing `>` placed on next line to remove white-space from the content which can cause vertical gaps in-between inline elements)

```
<div class="gallery">
    <img src="Toby1.jpg" alt="Toby close-up"
    ><img src="Toby1.jpg" alt="Toby close-up"
    ><img src="Toby1.jpg" alt="Toby close-up"
    ><img src="Toby1.jpg" alt="Toby close-up"
    ><img src="Toby1.jpg" alt="Toby close-up"
    ><img src="Toby1.jpg" alt="Toby close-up">
</div>
```

CSS: (`img` tags assigned `vertical-align: bottom;` to get rid of horizontal gaps between rows)

```
.gallery {
    width: 900px;
    }

    .gallery > img {
        vertical-align: bottom;
        }
```

[JSFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/Rxg8n/)

Comment: Just float the images to remove the gaps between them: http://jsfiddle.net/Rxg8n/1/. More reliable than counting on the exact layout of the markup.

Comment: Floating requires clearing afterwards which is another expense. Pros and cons I suppose. :)

Comment: That's why I added `overflow:hidden`...simple clear for a situation like this.

Comment: Indeed. I use that as well a lot (although dubiously since it's not the intended use of `overflow: hidden`). The risk of them ever implementing `overflow: hidden` any other way is probably nothing to worry about.

Comment: @SombreErmine Why did you say, "I do recommend against using a table as an image gallery. I would instead just place them all in a div and apply CSS heights, widths, paddings, and margins to your liking." when <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">...</table> is so simple and works perfectly?

Comment: It mostly has to do with accessibility technologies. Using `table` elements for anything other than tabular data can be confusing for certain screen readers. The secondary reasoning would be that using HTML tags in context of what they are intended for help various tools use that data correctly. Also, HTML5 is very focused on using correct semantics (since you say below that you want to learn HTML5). Various related keywords: Semantic HTML, WAI.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">...</table>
```

Comment: Yes! However, <http://validator.w3.org/unicorn/> tells me that " The cellpadding attribute on the table element is obsolete. Use CSS instead." and " The cellpadding attribute on the table element is obsolete. Use CSS instead." So I'll take a look at other answers. I do want to learn HTML5

Answer (score 0):

Your link is dead, so I'm not sure if you were originally using table-based layout to do this.

To do this without table-based layout, there are two steps you must take:

- Make sure there is no space between the `<img>` tags.  This will eliminate horizontal spaces between images.
- Put the `<img>` tags in a `div` element with a CSS style including `line-height: 0`.  This will eliminate vertical spaces between images.

There is an example and further explanation [here](http://www.moock.org/blog/archives/000309.html).